# Why can't npm just put everything in one place, like other package managers?

Tags: npm, npm-install

I'm trying to figure out why is it a bad idea to have packages installed globally.

Here's the quote from npm faq:
https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/faq#why-can-t-npm-just-put-everything-in-one-place-like-other-package-managers

> **Whatever, I really want the old style 'everything global' style.**
>
> Write your own package manager. You could probably even wrap up npm in a shell script if you really wanted to.
>
> npm will not help you do something that is known to be a bad idea.

WHAT?

I'm coming from ruby background. There's a package manager called `bundler` which installs all the gems (packages) globally (per ruby version). Whenever there's a new project and I run `bundle install`, bundler checks if there are already globally installed **compatible versions** of gems listed in `Gemfile` (`package.json`). If there are, bundler won't reinstall them globally or install them locally. The only requirement is to have all dependencies' versions satisfied.

For example:

There's a package A with dependency `C: '^1.0.0'`
and package B with dependency `C: '<1.2.0'`

Let's say package C has these versions available:
`'1.0.0', '1.1.0', '1.2.0'`

Bundler would then use package C version '1.1.0'. Otherwise, it would complain that your dependencies can't be matched.

How come it works for so many years for bundler, even before npm existed, and for npm it can't work?

Comment: Take a look at the following articles, they explain why npm dependencies are different, how it resolves dependency conflicts and name-spacing. [*How does npm compare to other packaging systems like Ruby gems and Python's pip?*](https://www.quora.com/How-does-npm-compare-to-other-packaging-systems-like-Ruby-gems-and-Pythons-pip) and [*Nested Dependencies*](http://maxogden.com/nested-dependencies.html) .